# NetSuite Single-Sign-On with WordPress website

Tags: wordpress, netsuite

I need to have my NetSuite web store share a login with my WordPress website.

I'm confused by all the ways it's sounds possible... i.e. Inbound, Outbound, OpenID, SAML, OAuth plugin, etc.

So far it looks like the SAML or OpenID methods might require a signed waiver or something to release NetSuite of responsibility.

This is the closest solution I've seen, which I think is NetSuite HTTP Outbound SSO... but I need something that will work will WordPress, preferably written in PHP:
[Using DotNetOpenAuth for NetSuite SuiteSignOn (Outbound Single Sign-on)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23226787/using-dotnetopenauth-for-netsuite-suitesignon-outbound-single-sign-on)

Please help, we've been bounced around from one customer support person to another... no clear answer on what the best or quickest solution would be... WordPress is so popular seems like there would be something semi-plug-and-play for using NetSuite as an authentication provider.

Answer (score 1):

NetSuite outbound SSO will allow a user who is logged in to your NetSuite site to be automatically logged in to your WordPress site.

Inbound SSO will allow a user who is logged in to your WordPress site to be logged in to NetSuite.

The outbound SSO is built into NetSuite, depending on your NetSuite package, you'll need to purchase an additional module if you want to do inbound SSO.

Comment: Well, it turns-out that NetSuite Inbound SSO does allow a user who is logged in to your WordPress site to be logged in to NetSuite... but it's kind of stupid and according to NetSuite developers requires a user record event, so the user would have to go to the NetSuite store and click something and then be redirected back to the WordPress site for it to work... This is too convoluted to be a feasible solution for our website visitors... so looks like we are going to have to punt and have manual NetSuite API calls like we did before with SOAP, only this time we might be able to use REST API.

Comment: You might want to try talking to a different NetSuite developer, it sounds like they might have been mixing up inbound and outbound sso.  Per the NetSuite documentation (which can be access here if you have a NetSuite Account https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/15042/), there shouldn't be a need for them to login to NetSuite first.  I've only implemented outbound SSO with NetSuite, so I can't speak from experience, but I would be surprised if what you were told was true.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your help, I will let you know if I get to the bottom of this. Cheers!